# Add $ next to price input inputted by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a recipe website made with rails and some haml on c9.io. On the show page, I'd like to display the price that the user inputted in a simple form with a dollar sign next to it. I tried using a `<p>` tag, however the dollar sign appears on another line.

Here is my show.html.haml file:

```
#post_show
%h1= @post.title
%p.username
    Shared by
    = @post.user.name
    about
    = time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)
.clearfix
    .post_image_description
        = image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)
        .description= simple_format(@post.description)
        %h6 Notes:
        .notes= simple_format(@post.notes)
        %h6 Price:
        %p
        .price= (@post.price) 


    .post_data
        = link_to "Visit Link", @post.link, class: "button", target: "_blank"
        = link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :get, class: "data" do
            %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up
            = pluralize(@post.get_upvotes.size, "Like")
        = link_to dislike_post_path(@post), method: :get, class: "data" do
            %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-down
            = pluralize(@post.get_downvotes.size, "Dislike")
        %p.data
            %i.fa.fa-comments-o
            = pluralize(@post.comments.count, "Comment")
        - if @post.user == current_user
            = link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "data"
            = link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "data"
    #random_post
        %h3 Check this out
        .post   
            .post_image 
                = link_to (image_tag @random_post.image.url(:small)), post_path(@random_post)
                .post_content
                    .title
                        %h2= link_to @random_post.title, post_path(@random_post)

                    .data.clearfix
                        %p.username
                            Share by
                            = @random_post.user.name
                        %p.buttons
                            %span
                                %i.fa.fa-comments-o
                                = @random_post.comments.count
                            %span
                                %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up
                                = @random_post.get_likes.size
 #comments
    %h2.comment_count= pluralize(@post.comments.count, "Comment")
        - @comments.each do |comment|
            .comment
                %p.username= comment.user.name
                %p.content= comment.content
        %h2 Share your opinion:
        = render "comments/form"
```

And here is my posts' form.html.haml:

```
    %div.container
  = simple_form_for @post do |f|
    = f.input :image
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :link
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :notes
    = f.input :price
    %br
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-info"
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
So now, I have added the following:

```
%span .input-group-addon $ .price= (@post.price)
```

However, the dollar sign is on the top line, and the price is on the bottom.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking how to add a dollar sign next to text that was inputted by a user on a showpage?

Answer (score 0):

p is block content so will cause a new line by default in html.  You can either handle this with CSS or use something that is inline like a span tag

Comment: I did 
    `%span`
    `.input-group-addon $ `
    `.price= (@post.price)`
However it still doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Haml input with preceding dollar sign just include in your code as you want to: 
Or just use classes:

```
.input-group
  %span.input-group-addon $
  %input.form-control{:placeholder => "Price", :type => "text"}/
```

Looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/1/

Comment: That's very useful, however I'd like the dollar sign to appear on the show page, next to the already inputed price.

Comment: Just put this line before %span.input-group-addon $